# MySQL return row if insert success, otherwise return 'failure'

Tags: mysql, insert, rowcount

My initial insert statement works fine, but I want to send a custom result back to my app.
Is this possible? (see the last SELECT statement below):

```
-- this is working    
INSERT INTO users (email, firstName, lastName, password)

SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT '{{email}}' as email, 
    'test' as firstName, 
    'person' as lastName, 
    '{{password}}' as password) AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = '{{email}}'
) LIMIT 1;

-- this statement is not working.
SELECT IF(ROW_COUNT() > 0, 
    SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '{{email}}', 
    'failure'
);
```

Running this gives me:

Error details: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = 'd@gmail.com', 'failure' )' at line 2

Comment: I doubt you can nest a select inside an IF like that. Do you really want the result to be a single value in the case of failure and an entire row in the case of non-failure? Seems like that's going to make the job of handling that in the application more painful rather than less.

Comment: Ok, I'd be happy to take a different approach if you can suggest it.  I just don't want to make another call to the server for the new record if it's successful.

Answer (score 0):

I think what your trying to do is something along:

```
SELECT IF(
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE email = '{{email}}') > 0,
    'success',
    'false'
);
```

Comment: No I'm trying to return the whole user row if inserted, not just a message if successful.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the last query with this worked:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE `id`= LAST_INSERT_ID()
```